# Not Able to Open Excel File When Hosting In IIS Server In Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, iis

I have developed an asp.net,c# application. In that application I have a task like open excel file, I've done the task when developing visual studio, **its working fine locally**.

but when I hosted my application into IIS server, it is not responding when I click read button.

My IIS Version - 7.5.7600

[image]

**Asp.Net Code:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Read">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkKpiName" Text='✉ Read' CommandName="View" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" CssClass="label" ForeColor="Green"></asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**C# Code :**

```
if (e.CommandName == "View")
{
   LinkButton lnkBtn = new LinkButton();
   lnkBtn.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");
   int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
   string FileName = ((Label)gvwUserManual.Rows[index].FindControl("lblFileName")).Text;
   ProcessStartInfo sInf = new ProcessStartInfo();
   sInf.FileName = "EXCEL.EXE";
   string XlsPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/SupportDocuments/" + Request.Cookies["BCookies"]["SessionUserName"].Trim().ToString() +"/" + FileName);
   sInf.Arguments = XlsPath;
   Process.Start(sInf);
}
```

Do I have give any permission to open excel file through IIS?

Comment: Why would you actually OPEN excel file in IIS on server? Why? What you need is to let your user to download it, not Open in IIS. when I saw `ProcessStartInfo` a big red flag went up

Answer (score 2):

You don't want Excel to start on your web server. Instead send the file to the user using [`Response.WriteFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyfzssz9(v=vs.110).aspx) e.g.

```
if (e.CommandName == "View")
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    string FileName = ((Label)gvwUserManual.Rows[index].FindControl("lblFileName")).Text;
    string XlsPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/SupportDocuments/" + Request.Cookies["BCookies"]["SessionUserName"].Trim().ToString() +"/" + FileName);

    // send file to user
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.WriteFile(XlsPath);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Something else you can do is use an [Office URI scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx) in the download links, if you are sure the user has Excel installed, so you contruct a hyperlink like so:

```
<a href="ms-excel:ofv|u|https://www.example.com/SupportDocuments/foo.xls">Open XLSX</a>
```

That `ms-excel:ofv|u|` prefix should get handled by Excel (if they have it installed).

The template for the download link might look like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# "ms-excel:ofv|u|" + new Uri(Request.Uri, "/SupportDocuments/" + your_filename_variable ).AbsoluteUri %>'
    Text="Read" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. i have tried the above  code but the excel file is getting downloaded. i don't want the file to be downloaded..what my requirement is when i click the read button the excel file need to open without downloading..

Comment: What you are describing is a user-controlled behavior.  Not an application-controlled behavior.

Comment: @Surya - You can't do that. It's 2017 and running arbitrary apps on the user's computer is not something you can do, for good reason.

Comment: @Surya I've added a possible solution that uses Office URI schemes (`<a href="ms-excel:..."`) that might work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need to do that, but anyway: the iis user that runs your web application, simply do not have that much rights to run the excel app, you can change your application pool Identity (IIS manager -> ApplicationPools -> "YourApplicationPool" Advanced Settings -> Identity), from `ApplicationPoolIdentity` to `LocalSystem`